# How can I prevent X windows from running when I boot Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: command-line, boot, xorg

Hi I want to boot Ubuntu quantal to a command prompt always and then use startx to launch x-windows if required. I have used the following methods but none work correctly.

1. update-rc.d -f lightdm remove   ---- does not work in quantal, works in debian sid.
2. I used the boot paramter 'text' on the grub command line. This does boot to console but then when I do startx only starts the server - no clients, if I do startx gnome-shell then gnome-shell runs but a lot of the initialisation is not done.
3. I also used start lightdm (after using the 'text' boot parameter). The problem is x starts with clients ok, but then when I exit X the server does not shutddown.

I would like to boot to a command prompt use startx to start gnome shell fully initialised, then on exit the x server should shutdown. I can do it fine in debian sid, ubuntu 12.04 but not ubuntu 12.10.
Any help with quantal would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
  Rob

Answer (score 1):

You should disable GDM, the GNOME Display Manager:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove
```

When you restart your computer, you’ll be presented with a text-mode login prompt instead of the graphical environment.

#### Run X.Org:

If you want to run the graphical environment, all you have to do is type the following command from the prompt, making sure to run it as your normal user account.

```
startx
```

#### Enable X.Org:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm defaults
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought the display manager was lightdm but I guess this uses gdm. I will give it a try. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi I have just tested it but it does not work. I did update-rc.d -f gdm remove. It reported all links gdm removed when I rebooted it has booted straight back into x windows. But in any case I thought the display manager was lightdm. Is there anything else I can try besides the 'text' boot parameter in grub2?

Comment: is gdm installed on your system?

Comment: @user91119 You were right initially. Ubuntu uses LightDM (unless you're using a quite old version of Ubuntu). Not GDM. (GDM is available if you want to use it, but LightDM is the default display manager.)

Answer (score 1):

No lightdm is the display manager, but as i said above update_rc.d -f lightdm remove does remove all the links but it still boots into x windows. This procedure works on my debian sid system but not in ubuntu 12.10. Canonical have obviously done something that does no use those sysvinit links. Thanks for your help. Rob